# How does the while statement in Prime#prime_division work?

Tags: ruby

I am solving problems on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problems) with ruby.

And I solve problem #3 by following code:

```
require 'prime'

division = Prime.prime_division(600851475143)
puts division.last.first
```

I decide to take a look on `Prime#prime_division` and here's the [code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb#L212):

```
def prime_division(value, generator = Prime::Generator23.new)
  raise ZeroDivisionError if value == 0
  if value < 0
    value = -value
    pv = [[-1, 1]]
  else
    pv = []
  end
  for prime in generator
    count = 0
    while (value1, mod = value.divmod(prime)
           mod) == 0
      value = value1
      count += 1
    end
    if count != 0
      pv.push [prime, count]
    end
    break if value1 <= prime
  end
  if value > 1
    pv.push [value, 1]
  end
  return pv
end
```

How does the `while` statement work?

```
while (value1, mod = value.divmod(prime)
       mod) == 0
 ...
end
```

I tried run it without newline `(value1, mod = value.divmod(prime) mod) == 0` but got error.

What does the newline stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses can contains multiple statements. (statements are separated by newline or `;`)

Following is related parts from [疑似BNFによるRubyの文法](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/spec=2fbnf.html)

```
COMPSTMT        : STMT (TERM EXPR)* [TERM]

TERM            : `;'
                | `\n'

PRIMARY         : `(' COMPSTMT `)'
                | ...
```

And the value of the last expression become the return value of the `(...)` expression.

```
(a = 1
 a + 1)
# => 2
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand it's multiple statements now, so actually it's just `mod == 0`. But I still can't figure out the `value1`. 
How does the value of `value1` change?

Comment: @evanc3, `divmod` returns an array of two items (one for quotient, other for remainder). For example `5.divmod(2)` returns `[2, 1]`.

Comment: @evanc3, So `values, mod = 5.divmod(2)` is like `values, mod = [2, 1]`. (parallel assignment or array unpacking ...); `values` is assigned 2, `mod` is assigned 1.

Comment: I missed the part of parallel assignment in my ruby learning. Thank you so much! It all makes sense now!